# Express receiving empty object

Tags: javascript, express, typescript, angular

I am trying to connect Angular 2 to Express. I have already setup and test the server endpoint using Postman (content type seems to be x-www-form-encoded for it to work) but other than that i do not know if there is any special config for angular 2 to carry that request. My guess its that the content-type is not correct or something.

form.ts

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from "angular2/core";
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, AbstractControl, Validators, Control} from "angular2/common";
import { Http } from "angular2/http";

@Component({
    selector: "parameters-form",
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: "dev/form.template.html"
})
export class ParametersForm {
  myForm: ControlGroup;

  systemParameters: AbstractControl;
  param: AbstractControl;
  liftOperator: AbstractControl;
  restrictOperator: AbstractControl;
  xInitial: AbstractControl;

  system_arr: number[];
  param_arr: number[];
  restrict_arr: number[];
  lift_arr: number[];
  xinitial_arr: number[];

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private _http: Http) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      "realisations" : ["", Validators.required],
      "numConstSteps" : ["", Validators.required],
      "timeHorizon": ["", Validators.required],
      "continuationStep" : ["", Validators.required],
      "continuationStepSign" : ["", Validators.required],
      "numberOfModelParameters" : ["", Validators.required],
      "systemParameters" : [""],
      "param" : [""],
      "netLogoFile" : ["", Validators.required],
      "numberOfModelVariables" : ["", Validators.required],
      "restrictOperator" : [""],
      "liftOperator" : [""],
      "xInitial" : [""]

    });
    this.system_arr = [];
    this.param_arr = [];
    this.restrict_arr = [];
    this.lift_arr = [];
    this.xinitial_arr = [];
    this.param = this.myForm.controls["param"];
    this.systemParameters = this.myForm.controls["systemParameters"];
    this.restrictOperator = this.myForm.controls["restrictOperator"];
    this.liftOperator = this.myForm.controls["liftOperator"];
    this.xInitial = this.myForm.controls["xInitial"];
  }

  addToArray(event, value: number, target: string): void {
    if (event.which === 13) {

      switch (target) {
        case "systemParameters":
          this.system_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.systemParameters).updateValue("");
          break;
        case "param":
          this.param_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.param).updateValue("");
          break;
        case "liftOperator":
          this.lift_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.liftOperator).updateValue("");
          break;
        case "restrictOperator":
          this.restrict_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.restrictOperator).updateValue("");
          break;
        case "xInitial":
          this.xinitial_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.xInitial).updateValue("");
          break;

      }
    }
  }

  deleteItem(value: any, target: string): void {
    let pos = 0;
    switch (target) {
      case "systemParameters":
        pos = this.system_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.system_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;
      case "param":
        pos = this.param_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.param_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;
      case "liftOperator":
        pos = this.lift_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.lift_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;
      case "restrictOperator":
        pos = this.restrict_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.restrict_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;
      case "xInitial":
        pos = this.xinitial_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.xinitial_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;

    }
  }

  isFullfilled(m: number, n: number) {

    if (
          m == this.restrict_arr.length
          && m == this.xinitial_arr.length
          && m == this.lift_arr.length
          && n == this.param_arr.length
          && n == this.system_arr.length
       ) {
         if (m != 0 && n != 0 ){
           return true;
         }

       }

       return null;
  }
  onSubmit(form: any): void {
    let form = form;
    form.systemParameters = this.system_arr;
    form.liftOperator = this.lift_arr;
    form.restrictOperator = this.restrict_arr;
    form.param = this.param_arr;
    form.xInitial = this.xinitial_arr;

    this._http.post("http://localhost:3001/export", form).subscribe();
    console.log("your submitted value:", form);
  }

}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/export', function(req, res){
  var body = req.body;
  res.send(body);
  console.log(body);
});

app.listen("3001", function(){
  console.log("Express server running on localhost:3001");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set explicitly the `Content-Type` header. Angular2 won't set it **under the hood** for you at the moment.

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-encoded');
this._http.post("http://localhost:3001/export", form, {
  headers: headers
}).subscribe();
```

Moreover you need to leverage the `URLSearchParams` class to build the body and convert it as a string. At the moment, the body can only be provided as a string to the `post` / `put` / `patch` method of the `Http` class.

```
var form = new URLSearchParams();
form.set('systemParameters', this.system_arr);
form.set('liftOperator', this.lift_arr);
(...)

this._http.post("http://localhost:3001/export", form.toString(), {
  headers: headers
}).subscribe();
```

Don't forget to import the `Headers` class:

```
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
```

Comment: just tried this, still receiving an empty object on console.log(req.body)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to provide the body as a string... I updated my answer. Otherwise do you see the `Content-Type` header in your request (dev tools in the browser)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @micronyks! I made updates in the same time so I had conflicts... so I merged things manually ;-)

Comment: here are my request headers  `(Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:el,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3001
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Yes, if you want to send a `application/json` content type. I read in your question that you want to send a `x-www-form-encoded` one. That's why I answered with the `URLSearchParam` class...

Comment: I can't see the `Content-Type` header in your request... Did you import the `Headers` class?

Comment: ah yes! about the headers i just said that it worked with those headers, but i have tried now with application/json and JSON.stringify and it worked thank you!. Also i tried to show the response back from server but it looks like this

Comment: `{ "_body": "{\"realisations\":\"\",\"numConstSteps\":\"\",\"timeHorizon\":\"\",\"continuationStep\":\"\",\"continuationStepSign\":\"\",\"numberOfModelParameters\":1,\"systemParameters\":[],\"param\":[],\"netLogoFile\":\"\",\"numberOfModelVariables\":\"\",\"restrictOperator\":[],\"liftOperator\":[],\"xInitial\":[]}", "status": 200, "statusText": "Ok", "headers": { "Content-Type": [ "application/json; charset=utf-8" ] }, "type": 2, "url": "http://localhost:3001/export" }` Is there a way to beautify this?

Comment: Try this: `this._http.post("http://localhost:3001/export", form, {
  headers: headers
}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe();`